# HTML/RoR layout table formatting

Tags: html, html-table

I'm just messing around with the format of an app I'm playing around with. It looks like this:

[image]

I'd like to use tables to get it so that everything under the "sd" will be directly next to it. like so:

[image]

How could I go about doing that... Using tables?

Here is my current code:

```
<div class ="individ_post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p>sd</p>
                <p>sd</p>
                <p>sd</p>
                <p>sd</p>
                <p>sd</p>
                <p>sd</p>
                <p>sd</p>

            </td>
        </tr>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>

            <tr>
                <td id="voting_deletion_table">
                    <div id="post_voting_and_deleting">
                        <div class="vote_score"><%= post.reputation_value_for(:votes).to_i %></div>
                        <br />
                        <% if user_is_logged_in? %>
                            <%= button_to "+", vote_group_post_path(@group, post, type: "up"), method: "post" %>
                            <%= button_to "-", vote_group_post_path(@group, post, type: "down"), method: "post" %>
                        <% end %>
                    </div>
                    <% if user_is_logged_in? && current_user.id == post.user_id %>
                        <td><%= button_to 'x', [@group, post], method: :delete, confirm: 'Are you sure?' %></td>
                    <% end %>
                </td>
                <td id="previow_of_post_table">
                    <div class ="preview_of_post">
                    <% if post.image_url %>
                        <%= image_tag post.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
                    <% elsif post.link %>
                        <%= extract_content_from_url(post.link) %>
                    <% end %>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td id="comments_table">
                    <div class ="post_author">@<%= post.user.username%>:</div> <div class ="post_title"><%= post.title %></div>

                    <% post.comments.each do |comment| %>
                    <div class ="post_comments">
                        > <span class="comment_username">@<%= comment.user.username %></span>:<%= comment.body %>
                    </div>
                    <% end %>

                    <% if user_is_logged_in? %>
                        <%= form_for([post.group, post, post.comments.build]) do |f| %>
                        <p>
                            <%= f.label :comment %><br />
                            <%= f.text_area :body, :rows => 3, :cols => 55 %>
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <%= f.submit %>
                        </p>
                        <% end %>
                    <% end %>

                </td>
        </table>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <br />

<% end %>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

CSS positioning using divs, something along the lines of position:relative (step 2 on [this page](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/))?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use TABLES for layouts. Use FLOATS.

Tables are for tabular data, and people stuck in 1999.

The structure would be something like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="labels">
       sd ... sd ...
     </div>
     <div class="controls">
         ...buttons...
     </div>
     <div class="formpanel">
         ...your form elements ....
     </div>
</div>
```

Set the widths for your elements, and use `float:left` for your inner DIV elements.